# What is "rabbit ear" in a video-capture context?

Tags: video

I was reading the [TVP5158 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tvp5158.pdf), and ran into a register bit that would enable "rabbit ear". What is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This patent](http://www.google.com/patents/EP0706741A1?cl=en) refers to "rabbit ears" as distortions in the video sync pulse. You can see why they're called that from the shape below.

http://www.patentgenius.com/image/5374960-2.html

[image]

Comment: Very plausible given the context of the device's register. The patent might also explain why TI didn't elaborate!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Cool!

Answer (score -1):

In a video context, rabbit ears usually refers to an antenna, so named because they look like ears sticking out of the top of your TV.

[image: Rabbit ears]

Comment: That was my answer too (now deleted), but Mike rightly pointed out that this is a *baseband* decoder, and that doesn't need an antenna.